# How to allow specific languages alphabet as a valid input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using this function to allow only letters as input in my `asp:Textbox`:

```
function Onlyletters(evt) {
    var e = event || evt;  
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    return ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode == 32) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123));
};
```

But, this will only allow the **English alphabet**.
I also need to allow the **Arabic alphabet**.. how to achieve that ?

Comment: Down Voting for no reason starting in 3 .. 2 .. 1 ... GO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add unicode for arabic alphabet in the condition. In this case I add 0600–06FF according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode). I am not familiar with Arabic language, so you may add more character code.

```js
function Onlyletters(evt) {
    var e = event || evt;  
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    return (
      (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || 
      (charCode == 32) || 
      (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) ||
      (charCode >= 0x0600 && charCode <= 0x06FF)
    );
};

function kp(evt){
  if(!Onlyletters(evt)){
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("keypress", kp);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
```

Comment: All i needed is this `(charCode >= 0x0600 && charCode <= 0x06FF)`